# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str while calling input taken for column numbers

Tags: python, arrays

so I am fairly new to python programming. I am facing a TypeError while trying to execute a program:
The error is in line 13,

```
while okay == 1:
    for line in open(r'%s'%path_F,'r'):
        line2 = line.replace('#','')  
        line2 = line.replace('column','')

        if '#' in line:
            data.append((line2.split()))

        if '#' not in line:
            for i in range(len(line.split())):
                name = 'column_%d' % (i)
                if name not in Column_data:
                    Column_data[name] = []
                a = (float(line.split()[i]))
                Column_data[name].append(a)
converge = np.array(data[0])
```

```
 File "D:\Karan\Python challenges (Skill-lync)\data-analysis\data_analysis2.py", line 148, in <module>
Column_data[str(name)] = []
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Please give us the traceback message.

Comment: Line 14 of what you've posted is `a = (float(line.split()[i]))`. It's that really what you meant by "line 14"?

Comment: What is your question? You get an error, so what? Why did you not change your code to fix the error?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I think the error is in`Column_data[name]`... What type is `name`?

Comment: I did try changing my code but a solution that I received was that the data type cannot be used as an index since it always a string when input is used and hence, it needs to be converted. I just don't know how to convert the str into integers or slices.

Comment: name is a string, if i'm not wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your error is saying that `Column_data[]` is a list, and you cannot call lists with string keys.`column_%d` being a string raises this error.

If you want to append `name` to Column_data[] you can use `append()`.

`Column_data.append[name]`